# Concrete price for YouTube API-Calls

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, price

In the quota calculation for YouTube, there is neither a currency nor a volume that the price refers to. Where do I find the pricing per API call?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube API quota calculator can be complicated thats why they created the calculator

> [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)
>
> This tool lets you estimate the quota cost for an API query. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.
>
> To use the tool, select the appropriate resource, method, and part parameter values for your request, and the approximate quota cost will display in the table. Please remember that quota costs can change without warning, and the values shown here may not be exact.

The cost is against your quota found in the developer console

[image]

I am not sure i understand what you mean by currency.  The YouTube api is a free api it doesnt cost anything to use.